# Combinar 2 bases de datos mediante algún patrón en R

Tags: base-de-datos, regex, r

Tengo una pregunta, es posible combinar 2 bases de datos en 1?

Tengo mis 2 bases de datos

Base 1

> ```
> Name V1   V2
> ABCD L21A J32F
> JKLM P21B R52L
> OPQR K31A L23P
> ```

en la base 2 donde dice código lo uso para hacer el código regex que me ayuda a filtrar mi base de datos donde agrego una linea que dice matches y me da el valor con el que encontro para ese utilizo

```
sapply(str_extract_all(base 1,regex), function(x) paste(x,collapse=","))
```

donde regex es una variable que hice con la base 2 y el codigo, ahora solo quiero pegar v1 y  v2  de la base 2 donde el regex haga match.

Base 2

```
codigo V1   V2
B.*C verde mediano
J.*K azul chico
Q.*R Morado grande
```

Base Final deseada

> ```
> Name    V1   V2  Codigo  V1      V2
>   ABCD L21A J32F  B.*C  verde  mediano
>   JKLM P21B R52L  J.*K  azul   chico
>   OPQR K31A L23P  Q.*R  Morado grande
> ```

No sé si es posible? ya lei varios post y no he podido lograrlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta solución es bien simple, ya que usa únicamente la funcionalidad "base", lo que si seguramente no es muy eficiente ya que básicamente se trata de hacer un "CROSS JOIN" entre ambos `data.frame` y luego filtramos usando `grep`. Veamos:

En primer lugar cargamos tu ejemplo, con algunos casos más para probar en dos `data.frame`:

```
txt1 <- "Name,V1,V2
ABCD,L21A,J32F
JKLM,P21B,R52L
OPQR,K31A,L23P
AXXX,L21A,J32F
AXJK,L21A,J32F
"

txt2 <- "codigo,V1,V2
B.*C,verde,mediano
J.*K,azul,chico
Q.*R,Morado,grande"

df1 <- as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(txt1), header=TRUE, sep=','))
df2 <- as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(txt2), header=TRUE, sep=','))

df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by=NULL)
df3[apply(df3, 1, function(x) grepl(x[4], x[1])),]
```

Teniendo los ejemplos en memoria, la solución es la siguiente:

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by=NULL)
df3[apply(df3, 1, function(x) grepl(x[4], x[1])),]
```

Sencillo y conciso: Merge de los datos y luego aplicamos un filtro entre las columnas 1 y 4 que son `codigo` y `Name`. El resultado:

```
   Name V1.x V2.x codigo   V1.y    V2.y
1  ABCD L21A J32F   B.*C  verde mediano
7  JKLM P21B R52L   J.*K   azul   chico
10 AXJK L21A J32F   J.*K   azul   chico
13 OPQR K31A L23P   Q.*R Morado  grande
```

Answer (score 2):

El paquete `fuzzyjoin::` tiene una función que te puede servir. La base a la que querés llegaar está complicada, porque tienen nombres de columna repetidos y eso no es posible en un data.frame (o al menos no deseable). Me refiero a V1 y V2. 
Además para esta función necesitarías que las columnas de empate tengan el mismo nombre. Al menos eso entiendo...
Acá va un ejemplo con tus datos:

```
library(tidyverse) #Para usar tribble() y crear los datos
library(fuzzyjoin) #Para regex_join

tribble(~Name, ~V1,   ~V2,
"ABCD", "L21A", "J32F",
"JKLM", "P21B", "R52L",
"OPQR", "K31A", "L23P") -> foo

tribble(
~Name,  ~V1, ~V2,               #Acá cambié un  nombre
"B.*C", "verde", "mediano",
"J.*K", "azul", "chico",
"Q.*R", "Morado", "grande") -> bar

regex_left_join(foo, bar, by="Name")
```

Resultado

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Name.x  V1.x  V2.x Name.y   V1.y    V2.y
   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
1   ABCD  L21A  J32F   B.*C  verde mediano
2   JKLM  P21B  R52L   J.*K   azul   chico
3   OPQR  K31A  L23P   Q.*R Morado  grande
```

No es exactamente el que estabas buscando, pero con un poco manipulación posterior funciona. Es decir, hace el join de los data.frames. Buscando en la documentación de fuzzyjoin podrías encontrar formas de ajustarlo a lo que necesitás.

Comment: Hola!, lo voy intentar y aviso si me funcionó. Gracias por los comentarios en la base qué voy utilizar las variables tienen nombres diferentes. Saludos